# Как используя QFileDialog загрузить в массивы численные данные в Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Создал диалоговое окно для выбора файла .txt. В этом файле будут находится данные для построения графика X и Y. Как сделать так чтобы при выборе файла числа загружались в массивы?

```
void MainWindow::on_action_3_triggered()
{

     QString fileName =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Открыть файл","C:/Users",QString::fromUtf8("Текстовые файлы(*.txt)"));
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример входных данных.

Comment: открыть файл и прочитать данные в массивы...

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали формат данных файла, для того, чтобы **начать** с ними работать простейшая схема такая: открыть файл, прочитать его данные (как вариант, в приведенном ниже примере, читаем файл целиком), обрабатываем прочитанные данные и закрываем файл:

```
QFile file(fileName);

//открываем файл с одновременной проверкой открытия
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    //если файл успешно открылся, читаем данные файла в data
    QByteArray data = file.readAll();

    //делаем что-то с прочитанными данными 
    /* (ТУТ мы только выводим эти данные, а что делать ВАМ, 
    зависит от формата данных, который вы не указали в вопросе)*/
    qDebug() << "DATA:" << data;

    //закрываем файл
    file.close();
}
```

Начните с этого и постарайтесь разобраться самостоятельно что делать с `data`. Готов **помочь** в разборе данных, если после многократных самостоятельных попыток не разберетесь